# Quickly rank variables in python

Tags: python, cython, ranking

I was wondering what the fastest way to sort variables is? I have 4 integer variables and I need to rank them quickly. This process needs to run many, many times so it needs to be quick. I tried using a counter and the counter().most_common() function which works well but is slower than just counting with individual variables. Here is an example of what I am running.

```
A = 15
B = 10
C = 5
D = 10

def get_highest(A,B,C,D):
    count = A
    label = 'A'
    if B >= count:
        count = B
        label = 'B'
    if C >= count:
        count = C
        label = 'C'
    if D >= count:
        count = D
        label = 'D'

    return count, label

highest, label = get_highest(A,B,C,D)
if label == 'A':
    A=0
if label == 'B':
    B=0
if label == 'C':
    C=0
if label == 'D':
    D=0
second_highest, label = get_highest(A,B,C,D)
```

I continue until I get the ranks of all the variables. I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this? I would also like to implement this in cython so answers that can be accelerated when implemented in cython would be appreciated.

Comment: why not use an array?

Comment: How do you know what's faster? How did you time the different things you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a faster alternative to your function:

```
import operator

def get_highest(A,B,C,D):
    return max(zip((A, B, C, D), 'ABCD'), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

However, if your goal, as it appears, is to zero out the maximum-valued variable, you may be better off having the function do even more:

```
def max_becomes_zero(A, B, C, D):
    temp = [A, B, C, D]
    maxind, maxval = max(enumerate(temp), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    maxname = 'ABCD'[maxind]
    temp[maxind] = 0
    return temp, maxval, maxname
```

to be called as follows:

```
(A, B, C, D), highest, label = max_becomes_zero(A, B, C, D)
```

Added: some may wonder (and did ask in comments) about relative speeds of `operator.itemgetter` vs a lambda.  Answer: don't wonder, **measure**.  That's what the `timeit` module in Python's standard library is **for**...:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'a="something"' 'max(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1])'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.56 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'a="something"; import operator' 'max(enumerate(a), operator.itemgetter(1))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.363 usec per loop
```

As you see, in this particular case (on my Linux workstation, and with Python 2.7.9), the acceleration of the whole operation is impressive -- more than 4 times faster, saving more than a microsecond per repetition.

More generally, avoiding `lambda` whenever feasible will make you much happier.

Note: it's important to time the **actual** operations -- putting preliminary ones such as the initialization of `a` and the `import` in the startup only, i.e in the `-s` flag for the (recommended) use of `timeit` from the command line in the `python -mtimeit` form; I suspect this mistake is what's apparently stopping a commenter from reproducing these results (just a guess as said commenter is **not** showing us the exact code being timed, of course).

Comment: is `perator.itemgetter(1)` (with import operator) faster than `lambda x : x[1]` ?

Comment: @Kasra, *measure* it -- with a `python -mtimeit`, ideally.  I'd better edit the answer to show how to do that...

Comment: i do it lambda is faster ,`using operator :  0.0570709705353
using lambda :  0.00878500938416` for `timeit(stmt=s1, number=100000` i  will be grateful if you learn the reason dear alex!

Comment: @Kasra, your data's impossible to interpret (what's `s1`? where's the close paren?-).  See mine, now at the end of my answer.

Comment: thanks for explain but i do it completely for instance i use s1 for `operator` and `s2` for `lambda` : `print 'using operator : ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=100000)
print 'using lambda : ',timeit(stmt=s2, number=100000)` but why python module timeit have difference with `-mtimeit` ?

Comment: You do not show `s1` nor `s2` so most likely is that you're erroneously **repeating** operations such as the `import

Answer (score 1):

The following takes sub-3µs on my machine to do the entire ranking:

```
In [43]: [name for (val, name) in sorted(zip((A, B, C, D), "ABCD"))][::-1]
Out[43]: ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C']

In [44]: %timeit [name for (val, name) in sorted(zip((A, B, C, D), "ABCD"))][::-1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.71 us per loop
```

Or how about this (I hope I got the comparisons right :-)):

```
def rank1(A, B, C, D):
  lA, lB, lC, lD = "A", "B", "C", "D"
  if A < B:
    A, B, lA, lB = B, A, lB, lA
  if C < D:
    C, D, lC, lD = D, C, lD, lC
  if A < C:
    A, C, lA, lC = C, A, lC, lA
  if B < D:
    B, D, lB, lD = D, B, lD, lB
  if B < C:
    B, C, lB, lC = C, B, lC, lB
  return (A, B, C, D), (lA, lB, lC, lD)
```

770ns for the entire ranking:

```
In [6]: %timeit rank1(A, B, C, D)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 765 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth trying to `sort` the variables:

```
ordered = sorted(list(zip("ABCD", (A, B, C, D))), key=lambda x: x[1])

>>> print(ordered)
[('C', 5), ('B', 10), ('D', 10), ('A', 15)]
```